# How to hide scroll down arrow when page has no scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have added scrolldown arrow in page, i want to hide arrow if page have no scroll, please help.

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function(){
   if($('.catagories-detail').hasScrollBar()){
       $("#scrollbtm").addClass("d-none"); 
   }
});

(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        return this[0] ? this[0].scrollHeight > this.innerHeight() : false;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: having overflow set to auto instead of scroll should solve this automatically.

Comment: my issue not resolved

Comment: Please add more details like HTML and CSS in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If the class ``d-none`` means ``display: none`` - why do you hide the button, when it has a scrollbar? Shouldn't it be ``if(!$('.catagories-detail').hasScrollBar()){``?